# Is there a way to enable metro on a 1024x600 netbook?

Tags: windows-8-preview, modern-ui

**Windows 8 Consumer Preview** works great on my 1024x600 netbook but, for some strange reason, Microsoft decided to provide its Metro interface only to 1024x768 and up screens.

"Strange" because Android can work with as little as 240x320 screens, and I know that Microsoft is presumably targeting smartphones, too, in its upcoming Windows 8.

The interface itself is there with all the panels etc. but when one of the rectangles is pressed, Windows 8 just refuses to launch any application (even Internet Explorer), except for Windows Explorer.

Looks to me like this isn't a real hardware limitation but some arbitrary flag set in the registry.

Is there any way or tweak to enable the Metro interface on 1024x600 screen?

Comment: Consumer preview is BETA software, other resolutions may be available when they are done developing Windows 8. Are there any video driver available for download for your tablet?

Comment: @Moab The reason is that Microsoft has decided on minimum hardware requirements of 1024x768 for screen resolution. It's not a beta issue.

Comment: Windows 8 is targeting tablets, not smartphones :)

Comment: Windows "Phone" 8 is completely different from Windows 8. Windows 8 runs on tablets, not phones.

Answer (score 2):

From [this](http://www.winsupersite.com/article/windows8/windows-8-consumer-preview-netbook-experience-142458) article on the WinSuperSite:

> Run Regedit (Start, "regedit", no quotes) and search for the term display1_downscalingsupported (using CTRL + F). Find each instance of this entry and change its value from 0 to 1. (Use F3 to repeat the previous search.) Do this until you've found them all, close Regedit, and reboot.
>
> You will now have additional resolution options. On my netbook, these are 1024 x 768 and 1152 x 864. I've found that the former looks better, but your mileage may vary. Voila! Metro apps now work.

The disadvantage of this is that the desktop will now look squished or skewed.